# jQueryUI Dialog - style not generated for buttons

Tags: jquery-ui

I use the the following code to show a dialog with jQuery UI:

```
var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
.text(msg)
.dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 140,
    modal: true,
    title: "Confirm",
    buttons: {
        "Yes": function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        },
        "Cancel": function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});
$dialog.dialog('open');
```

However, the buttons have no styles. I notice that the HTML generated for the buttons are:

```
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
    <button>Yes</button>
    <button>Cancel</button>
</div>
```

From the jQuery UI demos it is:

```
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
    <button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Ok</span></button>
    <button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Cancel</span></button>
</div>
```

I.e. the CSS styles are missing.
Do you know why?

Comment: Have you inserted jquery ui stylesheet? it's usually something like jquery.ui.all.css.

Comment: @alifity yes, it is the Button JS script that I missed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps because the CSS files are missing? Do you actually include them? Then use firebug or httpfox to see if there's a 404 somewhere...

Edit: I include a jQuery-ui css like this: `<link type="text/css" href="blah/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

Comment: In addition to this I'd suggest making sure your jquery-ui.js has the button scripts too: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js has all the ui elements.

Comment: @WSkid you're right! Thanks a lot! I guess it is because I didn't select the "Button" widget when downloading the jQuery UI custom JS. When using the jQuery UI JS from Google Ajax lib you mentioned, it works.

Answer (score 5):

If you use Bootstrap and JQueryUI, jquery-ui.js must be included AFTER bootstrap.js.